# how to generate graph by using two worksheets using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets in excel. 
i want to draw graph with two worksheets data using vba.
Please anybody help me

```
Range("G7:G11,A7:A11").Select
Range("A7").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData _  
    Source:=Range("Sheet1!$G$7:$G$11,Sheet1!$A$7:$A$11,sheet2!$D$4:$D$303,sheet2!$C$4:$C$303")
```

Comment: Well, we don't really know what your specific problem is, because you didn't state it, so it's hard to help! Check out the [FAQ] www.stackoverflow.com/faq for how to better ask questions on here to get good answers :). That said, I would make a table for your graph data on 1 sheet by linking the cells to the original data. That way you have all the data in one nice contiguous range, which is what Excel charts like the best.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this piecemeal. Create the chart with no series, then one by one add series (put this into a loop):

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    With .NewSeries
        .Values = {some range reference}
        .XValues = {some range reference}
        .Name = {range reference or string}
    End With
End With
```

The ranges can each be on different sheets, but you can't split a range across multiple sheets. So for example, the X and Y values of a series can be taken from different sheets, but all X values must come from one sheet, and all Y values must come from one sheet, but not necessarily the same sheet as the X values.